# Change main window title in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am making a text editor in Qt C++ and when I open a txt file I want to change the Title to the name of the file that is open I am aware of the `setWindowTitle("title go here")`. I was only able to display the path. here is a section of the function that open a new document.

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
            this,
            "TextEditor - Open" ,
            "C:\\",
            " Text File(*.txt);;All files (*.*)");

QFile file1(fileName);
    if((!fileName.isEmpty()))
     {
     currentFile = fileName;
     file1.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text);
     QTextStream in(&file1);
     QString str1 = in.readAll();
     ui->plainTextEdit-> setPlainText(str1);
     file1.close();
     statusBar()-> showMessage(" File successfully loaded! ");
     saveRecent(currentFile);
     }

    setWindowTitle(currentFile);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I formatted your Code and added the Code needed to show the correct Filename including the extension and excluding the Path.

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
            this,
            "TextEditor - Open" ,
            "C:\\",
            " Text File(*.txt);;All files (*.*)");

QFile file1(fileName);
if(!fileName.isEmpty())
{
     currentFile = fileName;

     file1.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text);
     QTextStream in(&file1);
     QString str1 = in.readAll();
     ui->plainTextEdit-> setPlainText(str1);
     file1.close();

     statusBar()-> showMessage(" File successfully loaded! ");
     saveRecent(currentFile);
 }
 // Create the FileInfo 
 QFileInfo file1Info(file1);

 // now get the fileName
 QString file1Name(file1Info.fileName());

 // Set the Title to the fileName
 setWindowTitle(file1Name);
```

See also the documentation of [`QFileInfo.fileName()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#fileName).

Answer (score 2):

```
QFileInfo fileInfo(file1);
QString filename(fileInfo.fileName());
```

Comment: As a short clarification: Your answer is 100% correct and solves the problem. I posted my own Answer with the same solution as yours as I don't like Code only Answers without even a link to the documentation, its just not my style. I gave you a +1 though because, technically, your answer is correct.

Comment: @Mailerdaimon Yup, that's why I deleted the comment.